# Reverse Engineering a Model from its MLE

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, weighted-regression

I want to find out the statistical model for which local linear
regression arises as a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE).

We are given data $\{ y_i \}_{i=1}^n$ with $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and
designs $\{ \mathbf{x}_i \}_{i=1}^n$ with $\mathbf{x}_i \in
\mathbb{R}^m$. Given these, we want to predict the response for a new
(unseen) $\mathbf{x}$.  We do this by defining a *local* linear model
$\beta( \mathbf{x} )$ that depends on the new design
$\mathbf{x}$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $\beta(
\mathbf{x} ) \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

A comment regarding the difference of this setup from standard
regression problems (be it homoskedastic or heteroskedastic). In a
standard regression problem, we seek a *global* linear model specified
by $\beta$, where $\beta$ only depends on what we have seen so far:
$y_i,i=1,...n$ and $\mathbf{x}_i,i=1,...,n$. It does not depend on a
new design $\mathbf{x}$ for which we would like to make a
prediction. In a standard regression problem we estimate $\beta$ from
what we have seen. Given a new $\mathbf{x}$ and asked what we predict
$y(\mathbf{x})$ to be, we usually predict $\hat{y}(\mathbf{x}) := \langle
\beta, \mathbf{x} \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a
vector dot product. This $\hat{y}$ is a Maximum Likelihood Estimator
(MLE) if we assume a linear model with Gaussian observation noise.

We specify a local linear model at every $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$
by giving lower weight (importance) to designs $\mathbf{x}_i$ that are
far from $\mathbf{x}$. As one can see below, this means we are using a
(differnet!) heteroskedastic model for each different
$\mathbf{x}$. The model is specified by defining $\beta( \mathbf{x} )$
as follows:

$$
\beta (\mathbf{x} ) := \arg\min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^n w( \|
\mathbf{x}- \mathbf{x}_i \| ) (y_i - \langle \beta, \mathbf{x}_i
\rangle )^2,
$$

for some weight function (e.g. $w(d) = \exp( -d )$). We can make
this look more familiar if we denote $W(\mathbf{x}) := diag(w
(\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i \| ) )$ and

$$
X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
--- & \mathbf{x}_1 & ---\\
--- & \mathbf{x}_2 & ---\\
    &  \vdots  &    \\
--- & \mathbf{x}_n & ---\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

then $\beta (\mathbf{x})$ is found to be

$$
\beta( \mathbf{x} ) = \arg\min_{\beta} (X\beta - y)^tW(\mathbf{x})(X\beta - y)
$$

If we are presented with a new (unseen) design $\mathbf{x}$ and asked
to predict a new response $y(\mathbf{x})$ we use $\beta(\mathbf{x})$
and predict

$$
\hat{y}(\mathbf{x}) = \langle \beta( \mathbf{x} ), \mathbf{x} \rangle.
$$

### My Question

What statistical model gives rise to a likelihood for which $
\hat{y}(\mathbf{x}) = \langle \beta(\mathbf{x}) ,\mathbf{x} \rangle$
is a maximum likelihood estimator? Or, what likelihood gives rise to
this estimator as its maximizer? Does this question even make sense?

What I view as the **main difficulty** is that this procedure tells you only how to predict a new value given old observations. This is in contrast with standard regression problems, where the model tells you (once you find $\beta$) how the old observations were generated as well.

### Some Thoughts

1. I was not able to find anything useful
   in the literature, references will be much appreciated.
2. If we consider the data as arriving sequentially we can decompose

$$
p(y_1,...,y_n|\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_n,\beta) =
 p(y_1|\mathbf{x}_1)p(y_2|\mathbf{x}_2, \beta_1) 
p(y_3| \mathbf{x}_3 ,\beta_2) \dots
$$
where $\beta_k(\cdot)$ is estimated as above using only the already
seen data $\{y_i \}_{i=1}^{k}$ and $\{ \mathbf{x}_i \}_{i=1}^{k}$.
Then we can take Gaussian likelihoods:

$$
p(y_i |\mathbf{x}_i ,\beta_{i-1}) := (2\pi \sigma_i^2)^{-1/2}
\exp (-\frac{1}{2\sigma_i^2} (y_i - \langle \beta_{i-1}(\mathbf{x}_i), \mathbf{x}_i \rangle )^2 ),
$$
where $\sigma_i^2$ can (perhaps) depend on the data but should be
estimated, which is a diffculty of its own. I do not like this view
too much, not sure why (the need to estimate $\sigma_i^2$ does not
help).

3. I like the one where we give a likelihood to $y_i$ based on all
   other observations, except itself. Define $y_{-i} := \{y_k \}_{k \neq
     i}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{-i} := \{ \mathbf{x}_k \}_{k \neq i}$. Then we
   may estimate $\beta_{-i}( \mathbf{x}_i )$ using $y_{-i}$ and
   $\mathbf{x}_{-i}$ (as explaine above) and let
   $$
   p( y_1,...,y_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}
     \exp (-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y_i - \langle \beta_{-i}(\mathbf{x}_i), \mathbf{x}_i \rangle )^2).
   $$
   I was not able to connect this to a statistical model, though. The
   variance $\sigma^2$ is not really important in this case, since it should not
   depend on $i$.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your notation, because you have overloaded "$\beta$" and the meaning of the expression "$\langle \beta(\bf{x}) ,\bf{x} \rangle$" is unclear: in what way might you be trying to distinguish this from matrix multiplication?  Regardless, this looks like a special case of weighted least squares, which is a heteroscedastic Gaussian model.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment. $\langle \beta(\bf{x}),\bf{x} \rangle$ is just a dot product, as I think you hinted. I don't believe this is simply a heteroskedastic Gaussian , since the noise amplitude changes as you change $\bf{x}$. As far as I know, a heteroskedastic model still gives rise to a unique $\beta$, whereas here we have a different one for each $\bf{x}$.

Comment: "Noise amplitude changes as you change $\mathbf x$" is precisely what heteroscedasticity means.  If you have a different $\beta$ for each $\mathbf x$, then your model is strikingly different from what your notation suggests.  Could you at least indicate what kinds of objects your symbols refer to and what the dimensions of all matrices and vectors might be?

Comment: @whuber thanks again. I have expanded the question based on your suggestions. I think it should make more sense now.

Comment: WHuber notes, "*If you have a different ββ for each ***xx***, then your model is strikingly different from what your notation suggests.*"  To me, this comment suggests that the OP is interested in some variant of a random effects, hierarchical model in an effort at identifying parameters for each new, observed ***xx***.

Comment: @DJohnson I am not sure what a random effects hierarchical model is. I took a look in Wikipedia but am not sure what are the similarities - I'll take a deeper look later. Thanks for the reference though.